# Messenger's webhook started ignoring admin's messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm currently developing a facebook bot. The app's status is "In Development". It's communicating with facebook messenger via webhook "messagee" events. It has been working correctly for a few months, and today the webhook has stopped reacting to my (admin's) messages. Other **Testers** added in App's Developer Settings can interact with it normally. I've been testing in a lot in the past few weeks, is there some limit for messages per user that I don't know of?

Comment: Check for facebook's api updates mb ?

Comment: Can't see any update news for today unfortunately.

Comment: @jbar did you find a way to listen admin messages?

Comment: the problem was with aws api gateway, not messenger at all